# inotifywait - exclude regex pattern formatting

Tags: regex, bash, shell, inotify

I am trying to use `inotifywait` to watch all ***.js*** files under my `~/js` directory; how do I format my regex inside the following command?

`$ inotifywait -m -r --exclude [REGEX HERE] ~/js`

The regex - according to the man page, should be of POSIX extended regular expression - needs to match "all files except those that ends in ***.js***", so these files can in turn be excluded by the `--exclude` option.

I've tried the (?!) lookaround thing, but it doesn't seem to work in this case. Any ideas or workarounds? Would much appreciate your help on this issue.

Comment: You don't need to use `-r` or `--exclude`. Just run: `inotifywait -m ~/js/*.js`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I've tried the (?!) thing

This thing is called negative lookahead and it is not supported by POSIX ERE.

So you have to do it the hard way, i.e. match everything that you want to exclude.

e.g.

`\.(txt|xml)` etc.

Comment: Is it possible to do it using the [^ ] metachar? I tried .*?[^\.][^j][^s]$ ....... Doesn't work as intended either.

Answer (score 8):

`inotifywait` has no include option and POSIX extended regular expressions don't support negation. (Answered by [FailedDev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943555/3377535))

You can patch the inotify tools to get an `--include` option. But you need to compile and maintain it yourself. (Answered by [browndav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19455631/3377535))

A quicker workaround is using `grep`.

```
$ inotifywait -m -r ~/js | grep '\.js$'
```

But be aware of grep's buffering if you pipe the output to another commands. Add `--line-buffered` to make it work with `while read`. Here is an example:

```
$ inotifywait -m -r ~/js | grep '\.js$' --line-buffered |
    while read path events file; do
      echo "$events happened to $file in $path"
    done
```

If you just want to watch already existing files, you can also use `find` to generate the list of files. It will not watch newly created files.

```
$ find ~/js -name '*.js' | xargs inotifywait -m
```

If all your files are in one directory, you can also use [ostrokach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943528/inotifywait-exclude-regex-pattern-formatting#comment50688369_7943528)'s suggestion. In that case shell expansion is much easier than find and xargs. But again, it won't watch newly created files.

```
$ inotifywait -m ~/js/*.js
```

Comment: Acually `--include` works out of the box now, although it is not documented still.

Comment: @1234ru it is not present in the manpages, but it is present in the `--help` output of version 3.20.1

Comment: I don't have the `--include` option in RedHat 7

Answer (score 4):

I posted a patch here that adds --include and --includei options that work like negations of --exclude and --excludei:

https://github.com/browndav/inotify-tools/commit/160bc09c7b8e78493e55fc9f071d0c5575496429

Obviously you'd have to rebuild inotifytools, and this is relatively untested, but hopefully it can make it in to mainline or is helpful to someone who comes across this post later.

Comment: I updated the include regex patch a little & added it to Alpine Linux as inotify-tools-inc http://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/commit/?id=7ee2363baf3fda4d5e66ae285a658b73d1fdd281

Comment: Thankfully, your patch or what your patch tried to accomplish is now upstream. When I compiled from the master branch https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools.git, I see the two options you spoke about.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are quoting the regex command, if you are using shell-relevant characters (including `()`).

While this is working:

```
inotifywait --exclude \.pyc .
```

this is not:

```
inotifywait --exclude (\.pyc|~) .
```

You have to quote the entire regular expression:

```
inotifywait --exclude '.*(\.pyc|~)' .
```

Answer (score 2):

As of version 3.20.1, inotifywait does include the `--include` and `--includei` options.

To see them, run `inotifywait --help`.  For some reason, they aren't documented in the manpages.

Answer (score 1):

You could get most of this with `--exclude '\.[^j][^s]'` to ignore files unless they contain `.js` at some point in the filename or path.  If you combine it with `-r` then it will work with arbitrary levels of nesting.

Only drawback is filenames like `test.js.old` will still be watched and all files inside a directory called `example.js/` will also be watched, but this is probably somewhat unlikely.

You could probably extend this regex to fix this but personally I don't think the drawbacks are a big enough of a deal to worry about.