# inotifywait To run command based on type of file modified

Tags: regex, bash, inotify, watch, inotify-tools

I'm specifically trying to simultaneously watch 2 different filetypes in 2 subdirectories:

.coffee filetypes in the 'js' subdirectory
  .styl filetypes in the 'css' subdirectory

I only know so much bash and I'm trying to get something like this to function

```
while inotifywait --format %w%f ./{css,js}/*.{styl,coffee}; do
  # regex pattern to match the file ending
  # and define it to $ending

  if[ $ending == coffee ]
  then
   coffee -c $file
  elif[ $ending == styl ]
  then
    stylus -c $file
  fi
done
```

// Edit //
modified this line:

```
while inotifywait --format %w%f ./{css,js}/*.{styl,coffee}; do
```

So now it checks both files but if there's no .coffee files on the css folder, or .styl files in js, it returns an error that no files were found.

Additionally I noticed when I run this script, it returns/runs the following 3 times

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
./css/styles.styl
```

Comment: inotifywait uses POSIX Extended Regular Expressions and it is limited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943528/inotifywait-exclude-regex-pattern-formatting Just separate these scripts: one per coffee/js and one per styl/css

Answer (score 2):

Not the cleanest solution but works

```
#!/bin/sh

while file=$(inotifywait -r -e modify --format "%w%f" ./); do
  EXT=${file##*.}
  if [ $EXT = "styl" ]
  then
    stylus -c $file
  fi
  if [ $EXT = "coffee" ]
  then
    coffee -c $file
  fi
done
```

If you have a better solution that only watches the files I want, then I'm all ears