# Regex with inotifywait to compile two types of file in golang

Tags: regex, bash, inotify

I use a [script](https://github.com/alexedwards/go-reload) to auto-compile in golang with inotifywait. But this script only checks files with the extension .go. I want to also add the .tmpl extension but the script uses regular expressions. What kind of changes I have to make to this line to get the desired result?

```
inotifywait -q -m -r -e close_write -e moved_to --exclude '[^g][^o]$' $1
```

I've tried to concatenate with | or & and other things like ([^t][^m][^p][^l]|[^g][^o])$ but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does the above work with `file.ao` or `file.ga`? I doubt it.

Comment: @stribizhev i've tried in https://regex101.com/ and it worked

Comment: `.ao` and `.ga` are [not matched](https://regex101.com/r/hZ4tJ7/1). If that is what you need, then OK.

Comment: @stribizhev is exactly that what I need. Try this list (width /gm):
.go
.og
.ao
.ga
.got
.ext
.properties
main.a

Comment: You seem to have used a zero instead of `o` in `([^t][^m][^s][^l]|[^g][^0])$` (and also `s` instead of `p`).

Comment: @stribizhev I have not used a 0, the error was when I wrote here

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7943528/2088135 (in fact, the comment from there was what I based my answer on).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use a regex to exclude two types of file, why don't you just only watch those files?

```
inotifywait -q -m -r -e close_write -e moved_to /path/**/*.{go,tmpl}
```

To use the `**` (which does a recursive match), you may have to enable bash's globstar:

```
shopt -s globstar
```